# Django - Not able to set view using a front end folder which is outside app folder structure

Tags: django

> I have found my solution , please check answer below .This happened
>   because I was exploring answers for previous version of Django .

I am new to Django , i have learnt most the basics in framework in past one month .I have deployed my application from local to an online server .The REST APIs are working fine but now I am not able to access my front end code on that server because Django is on the server's root .

There is sepration of concerns between server and front end code so I had developed my UI by not worrying about directory structure as per Django ( for example static file confiuration etc. )

Now I want to use Django on local server's root and access my **/front-end/html/index.html** as home page .

Please see all code and directory strcture as follows with error :

I am always getting following error :

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
index.html
Exception Location: C:\Users\didi\Envs\wantedly_virtual_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in select_template, line 47
Python Executable:  C:\Users\didi\Envs\wantedly_virtual_env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.3
```

My urls.py file is as follows :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r"^$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
    url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    url(r'^rest-auth/login/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    url(r'^refresh-token/', refresh_jwt_token),
    url(r'^user/$', DetailsView.as_view(), name='rest_user_details'),
    url(r'^', include('api.urls')),
    url(r'^api/v1/skills/$', wantedly_app_views.skill_collection),
    url(r'^api/v1/skills/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', wantedly_app_views.skill_element),
    url(r'^api/v1/user/skills/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', wantedly_app_views.user_skill_collection),
    url(r'^api/v1/user/skill/upvotes/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', wantedly_app_views.user_skill_upvotes),

]
```

My settings.py contains following template structure - i am not able to use relative path here so I am hardcoding full path :

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    ('C:/code/django/wantedly/front-end/html').replace('\\','/'),
)

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```

My directory structure is as follows :
[image]

Template loader postmorterm :

```
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\didi\Envs\wantedly_virtual_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\didi\Envs\wantedly_virtual_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\didi\Envs\wantedly_virtual_env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\didi\Envs\wantedly_virtual_env\lib\site-packages\allauth\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
```

Comment: When django raised TemplateNotFound exception, it would've listed out the directories where it tried to look for the template, can you please list out these directories in your question.

Comment: @at14 I have updated question with template loader info at end .

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution , since 1.8 the Django has depricated specifying template tuples in explicit variable TEMPLATE_DIRS , instead it should be an array for **TEMPLATES** as follows :

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
                'C:/code/django/wantedly/front-end/html',
            ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```